# Jquery swap image gallery on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L1o9xg28/)** for my question.

In my demo you can see when you hover over the thumbnail image with the mouse the bigger picture is changing. What i want to? I want to change the images automatically after a few second.

What i need to do for it ? Anyone can help me ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#magazin_sldwr li img").hover(function(){
        $('#mainm-img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''));
    });
    var imgSwap = [];
     $("#magazin_sldwr li img").each(function(){
        imgUrl = this.src.replace('thumb/', '');
        imgSwap.push(imgUrl);
    });
    $(imgSwap).preload();
});
$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a start : **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ev82vbou/)**

The idea is to use an `.active` class on the parent `li` of the current image, and then trigger a `mouseenter` event every 2 seconds :

```
function autoChangeImage() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#magazin_sldwr li.active")
            .removeClass('active')
            .next('li')
            .addClass('active')
            .children('img')
            .trigger('mouseenter');
        autoChangeImage();
    }, 2000);
}
```

Of course, you will probably want to go back to the first thumb after having reached the last one, and `clearTimeout` when hovering a thumb "manually" : **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ev82vbou/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

use `setInterval()`

```
setInterval(function() {
    //change image
}, 2000);
```

Where 2000 is the number of miliseconds. For o ly one change you can use `setTimeout()`